# How to use escape sequences in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using `python 2.7.13` and I am a beginner.

My scenario is escape sequences are not working in command prompt, I have attached an image, and please can anyone tell me that what was wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: try `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Comment: In Python 2.7, `print` is a _statement_ not a _function_. However, you can give the `print` statement "function-like" behavior by doing `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file.

Comment: If you change the print statement as I indicated, it will display properly

Answer (score 0):

If by escape sequences, you mean the '/n', that is because you are using the print function to print a list/tuple of values.

If you use string formatting it will give you what you expect:

```
print("Your amount %s consists of \n%s dollars\n" % (amount, totaldollars))
```

The %s is a placeholder, just like in most other languages.  The variables "amount" and "totaldollars" get substituted from the tuple on the other side of the '%'